# How can I detect at runtime if a library without objects has been loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, frameworks

I am working on an SDK. It links to a number of 3rd party SDK's, but not every user of my SDK will need to use their SDK's. I am constructing my project to use build iOS dynamically linked frameworks. This works well when the third party SDK is written in Objective-C since I can call:

```
[ThirdPartySDK class];
```

and detect if it is loaded. However, I am importing at least one framework that just defines functions and structs and other such non-object types. Is there any way to detect if a library like this has been loaded?

Comment: Pretty sure that's what you're looking for. Just ping me if not.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Perfect, thanks Josh.